# show form-control only when value chosen on previous form-control with html and php

Tags: php, html, form-control

I am creating a webpage with from-controls (2 in this exemple).
My code is the following :

```
<body>

    <div class="option_choice_global">
         Select your options 

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <label> Application </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="application">
                <?php 
                    $applications = get_apps(); 
                    foreach ($applications as $key => $value) { echo '<option value='.$key.'>'.$value.'</option>'; }
                ?> 
            </select>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label> Version </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="version">
                <?php 
                    $versions = get_versions(); 
                    foreach ($versions as $key => $value) { echo '<option value='.$key.'>'.$value.'</option>'; }
                ?> 
            </select>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-xs-12">   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="fonction_submit_graph(this)">  <b> Submit </b>  </button>
        </div>                     
    </div>  

</body>
```

But I would like the second one (the version) to appear only when a value on the first controller (the application) is chosen. And my function get_versions() will then depend on the selected application :  get_versions(application_number).

How can I do to show the second controller only when a value on the first one is selected ? And to get the selected value ?
Thank you!

Comment: tried using `IF` statement ?

Comment: You need to put that section in another  file or the same file in a diffrent function and on select AJAX call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to show the second `select` dropdown after a value is chosen from the first.

This can easily be done with JavaScript and CSS:

- In the second `select` tag, add these attributes: `style="{display: none;}"`. This will hide the dropdown. Also give it `id="select2"` for easy identification.
- In the first `select` tag, add this attribute: `onchange=showHiddenSelect();` This causes a function to be called when the value changes ie an option is selected. Also give it an `id="select1"`.
- Somewhere in your document, define the `showHiddenSelect` function like this: 

  function showHiddenSelect() {
    document.getElementById("select2").style.display="block";
  }

If you also wish to get the selected value, you'd just add this in that function: `var select1value = document.getElementById("select1").value;` and do what you want with it.

If you need the selected option from `select1` to be sent to a backend and then used to calculate the options for `select2`, then your best bet would be to use AJAX to send and receive data from a script and then populate the select with JavaScript.

Comment: The following is not working :       
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: 'setup_data.php',
            data: {'var':select1value, 'type':'test'},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                var options = '';
                for (var prop in data) {
                    options += '<option value="' + prop + '">' + data[prop] +'</option>';
                }
                $('#version').html(options);
            }
        });

with 
<select class="form-control" id="version"></select>

Comment: That might depend on the data returned by your `setup_data.php`. Are you sure that script returns the right data to you?

Comment: I change the code into setup_data.php and it works. Thank you Shalvah for you help!